# React Intl, how to add a number in a message?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I have a `en.json` file as below:

```js
{
    "doorClosing": {
      "defaultMessage": "Doors closing",
      "description": "Elevator doors are being closed"
    },
    "floorSelected": {
      "defaultMessage": "Floor selected: {floorSelected}",
      "description": "`The floor ${lift.floorSelected} has been selected`"
    },
    "floorSelectedInvalid": {
      "defaultMessage": "Invalid floor",
      "description": "The selected floor is not valid"
    },
    "idle": {
      "defaultMessage": "",
      "description": ""
    },
    "init": {
      "defaultMessage": "Initialisation",
      "description": "The system is being initialized"
    },
    "liftMoving": {
      "defaultMessage": "Elevator moving",
      "description": "Elevator is being moved to the floor selected"
    }
}
```

Then later in the code, I use `let dashboardMsg = intl.formatMessage({id:msg});` where msg is one of the key contained in the json file.
About the key `floorSelected`, when I use it `${lift.floorSelected}` is not translated by the number contained in this variable.
What's wrong? Is there another way or do I have to do that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called *formatted argument*. It's part of the ICU Message Syntax which you can see [here](https://formatjs.io/docs/core-concepts/icu-syntax) for more reference.

```json
"floorSelected": {
  "id": "floorSelected",
  "defaultMessage": "Floor selected: {floorSelected}",
  "description": "The floor {floorSelected} has been selected"
},
...
```

In your code

```js
const message = intl.formatMessage(messages.floorSelected, {
  floorSelected: lift.floorSelected
});
```

You can also specify the [number type](https://formatjs.io/docs/core-concepts/icu-syntax/#number-type) for the argument to customize how the number should be formatted. Here is an example:

```
Number: {num} {num, number, ::currency/USD} {num, number, ::compact-long}
```

When you call this method

```js
intl.formatMessage(messages.numberExample, {
  num: 4200
})
```

It will be translated to this

```
Number: 4200 $4,200.00 4.2 thousand
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64122522/react-intl-how-to-add-a-number-in-a-message]

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your help

Comment: your solution seems to be correct but I'm now getting an exception: [React Intl Error FORMAT_ERROR] Error formatting message: "idle", using id as fallback. 
Locale: fr
MessageID: idle
Default Message: undefined
Description: undefined

Comment: I'm trying to follow the steps there: [https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/message-distribution](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/message-distribution)

Comment: By compiling my json file, this solution works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables via `values` prop:

```
"floorSelected": {
  "id": "selected.floor",
  "defaultMessage": "Floor selected: {floorSelected}",
}

//...

let dashboardMsg = intl.formatMessage({id:msg, values: {floorSelected: 5})
```

Not sure if this is gonna work for description though.

Answer (score 0):

[formatMessage](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#usage) takes a message descriptor and optional values object as arguments.

```
formatMessage(messageDescriptor, values);
```

For your case

```
formatMessage({ id: msg }, { floorSelected: 3 })
```

If you ensure you add an `id` property to all your message descriptors then you won't need to construct an object with it on the fly each time you want to render the text.